# Forgot Password link in an android application

Tags: android

In my android application, I have a "Forgot Password" link which opens a new activity that contains a TextView (to enter the email) and a button. What I have to add as activity button to send the password by email

Answer (score 0):

you must have a server(website, host,..) that response for your request, when user pressed the button , you have to take his email from editText then send it to your server then take action from there

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@emailaddress.com");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```